# switch database in sql postgres

Tags: postgresql, docker

I am trying to create a POSTGRES db image with all my databases and schemas being intialized on start up as follows,

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  iamstorepg:
    image: library/postgres:10
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=pgiam
      - POSTGRES_USER=iam
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=iam
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - "./schema1.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/1-schema.sql"
      - "./schema2-db.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/2-schema.sql"
```

here in 2nd sql file i am trying to create another DB and intialize it with all the needed table as follows,

```
CREATE DATABASE DB1
    WITH
    OWNER = iam
    ENCODING = 'UTF8'
    CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE DB1 to iam;
/*\connect DB1;

DROP SCHEMA public CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA public;
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA public TO iam;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO iam;*/
---

-- Drop table
DROP TABLE IF exists DB1.public.user_involvements;
----- New proposition user-rol -> role-resource relationship one to many
-- Create User-roles table (authorisations or involvements , however you would like to call it)
CREATE TABLE pgiamrolestore.public.tb1(
    id uuid NOT NULL,
    path varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    code varchar(255) not null,
    is_active bool NOT null default true
);
```

problem here is that even though second database is being created, i am not able to specified table in it and this table TB1 is being created in 1st DB 'PGIAM'. is there a way i can resolve this?

Comment: You need to connect to the new database. Are you running your commands using `psql`? Then give the name of new database on command line or use command `\connect`

Answer (score 1):

I changed my sql file to shell and i am able to run \c command to switch database as follows,

```
    #!/bin/bash
    set -e
    psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "$POSTGRES_USER" --dbname "$POSTGRES_DB" <<-EOSQL
        CREATE DATABASE DB1
            WITH
            OWNER = iam
            ENCODING = 'UTF8'
            CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;
        
        GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE DB1 to iam;
        /*\connect DB1;
        
        DROP SCHEMA public CASCADE;
        CREATE SCHEMA public;
        GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA public TO iam;
        GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO iam;*/
        ---
        
        -- Drop table
        DROP TABLE IF exists DB1.public.user_involvements;
        ----- New proposition user-rol -> role-resource relationship one to many
        -- Create User-roles table (authorisations or involvements , however you would like to call it)
        CREATE TABLE pgiamrolestore.public.tb1(
            id uuid NOT NULL,
            path varchar(255) NOT NULL,
            code varchar(255) not null,
            is_active bool NOT null default true
        );
    EOSQL
```